# Spring boot how to return json embedded in object structure

Tags: json, spring-boot

In my Spring-boot controller I have an endpoint that returns the following data structure:

```
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Map<String, Object>>> getComplexStructure()
```

The inner `Object` in this structure is saved as raw JSON String in the database and I don't use the actual value in my application. Currently I have to Deserialize that JSON into an Object so that I can return it from the function, so that Spring can Serialize it into JSON again. That sounds inefficient and I was wondering could I somehow skip that Deserialize Reserialize part and just return the raw JSON for Spring to embed in the serialized datastructure surrounding it.

Now obviously if I just return the String like this:

```
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Map<String, String>>> getComplexStructure()
```

the JSON parser will put the string in quotation marks and escape it and it will just be a string and not a json structure.

**Is there some annotation or something I could do to skip the unnecessary Serialization and Deserialization of that embedded JSON?**

*Reading this it sounds very simple, if there are some good technical terms for this process, please also mention them, it will make googling easier :)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AbstractHttpMessageConverter` for custom mapping operations for your problem.

```java
import org.springframework.http.HttpInputMessage;
import org.springframework.http.HttpOutputMessage;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Component
public class CustomMessageConverter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<Map<String, Map<String, Object>>> {
    public CustomMessageConverter() {
        super(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return HashMap.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, Map<String, Object>> readInternal(Class<? extends Map<String, Map<String, Object>>> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeInternal(Map<String, Map<String, Object>> value, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
        PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(outputMessage.getBody());

        printStream.print("{");

        // track to put comma between items
        boolean printedEntry = false;

        for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, Object>> entry : value.entrySet()) {
            /* // if you want to disable null print uncomment it
            if (entry.getValue() == null) {
                continue;
            }
            */
            if (printedEntry) {
                printStream.print(",");
            }

            printStream.print("\"" + entry.getKey() + "\":");
            if (entry.getValue() == null) {
                printStream.print("null");
                continue;
            }

            // INNER ENTRY LOOP
            printStream.print("{");
            // track to put comma between items
            boolean printedInnerEntry = false;
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> innerEntry : entry.getValue().entrySet()) {
                if (printedInnerEntry) {
                    printStream.print(",");
                }
                printStream.print("\"" + innerEntry.getKey() + "\":");
                printStream.print(innerEntry.getValue());
                printedInnerEntry = true;
            }
            printStream.print("}");

            printedEntry = true;
        }
        printStream.print("}");
    }
}
```

### Test

```java
@RestController
public class HomeController {
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Map<String, Object>>> getComplexStructure() {
        Map<String, Map<String, Object>> result = new HashMap<>();

        Map<String, Object> innerItem1 = new HashMap<>();
        innerItem1.put("bar1", "{\"item\": 12, \"list\": [1, 2]}");
        innerItem1.put("bar2", "{\"item\": 22, \"test\": \"test@\"}");

        result.put("foo1", innerItem1);

        Map<String, Object> innerItem2 = new HashMap<>();
        innerItem2.put("tail1", "{\"item\": 55}");
        innerItem2.put("tail2", "{\"item\": 77}");

        result.put("foo2", innerItem2);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
    }
}
```

`GET http://localhost:8080/`

Output

```json
{"foo1":{"bar1":{"item": 12, "list": [1, 2]},"bar2":{"item": 22, "test": "test@"}},"foo2":{"tail1":{"item": 55},"tail2":{"item": 77}}}
```

### Caution

I recommend that create a new class for operating this special case. Because `HashMap` is generic and caught all unrelated returns extended from `HashMap`. So, if you want to prefer this way, you can change below codes.

Create a new return type from `HashMap<String, Map<String, Object>>`

```java
public class CustomMessage extends HashMap<String, Map<String, Object>> {
}
```

In `CustomMessageConverter` change `supports` method with below.

```java
@Override
protected boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
   return CustomMessage.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
}
```

Also, you can change `AbstractHttpMessageConverter<CustomMessage>` instead of `AbstractHttpMessageConverter<Map<String, Map<String, Object>>>` but it doesn't required.

Change return type with this new class.

```java
public ResponseEntity<CustomMessage> getComplexStructure() {
   CustomMessage result = new CustomMessage();
   ...
   return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
}
```

Comment: Don't miss the `Caution` section. It can be useful for mapping only the methods that you want.

Comment: I was actually writing a comment about how I can prevent all Hashmaps from being affected and then you added the caution section. So I scrapped my comment :D